# SQL update with inner join and count

Tags: sql

I can't get this to work... Any ideas?

```
update Products
set UnitPrice = UnitPrice * 0.9
from Products p
inner join [Order Details] od
on p.ProductID = od.ProductID
where COUNT(p.ProductID) > 50
```

An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Thanks

Comment: Saying "I can't get this to work..." isn't very helpful. Describe the problem, or better yet, post the error message.

Comment: Did you try with Having clause?

Comment: @Hari yes, no luck with having

Comment: I think that the problem is in "where COUNT(p.ProductID) > 50", COUNT goes in HAVING, not WHERE. See this for more info: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

Comment: @arielsp - Saying "no luck with having..." isn't very helpful. What error message do you get?

Comment: @Tony Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'HAVING'.

Comment: Are you trying to reduce the unit price of a product by 10% if there has been for than fifty orders for that product?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
update p
set UnitPrice = UnitPrice * 0.9
from Products p
inner join (
    select ProductID
    from [Order Details]
    group by ProductID
    having count(*) > 50
    ) as od
on od.ProductID = p.ProductID
```

Answer (score 3):

probably something like this, depends on your rdbms, you should tag this accordingly

```
update Products set UnitPrice = UnitPrice * 0.9
where ProductID in (
    select ProductID from [Order Details]
    group by ProductID
    having count(*) > 50)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `HAVING` clause instead of `WHERE` in your query

Answer (score 0):

Can be done without JOIN:

```
update Products set UnitPrice = UnitPrice * 0.9
from ( select ProductID
    from [Order Details]
    group by ProductID
    having count(*) > 50 ) a 
where Product.ProductID=a.ProductID
```